# Saving an Mutable array of images and loading them

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I have part of my app that will take a photo and the person can elect to save it i then save the image to an array but what ways can I save it to the phone WITHOUT it being put in the photo library. I tried

```
UIImage *image = imageView1.image;

[array addObject: image];

NSUserDefaults *default = [NSUserDefault standardDefaults];
[defaults setObject:image withKey:@"saved image"]; //not exact code just showing the method
```

I use to save the array of images

```
[defaults synchronize];
```

then i also use `UserDefaults` to load array but it does not work. I am wondering if there is a different way to save images without saving them to the photo library.

Comment: Save the image data to disk and the path you saved it to in defaults.

Comment: Or convert them to base64 string and save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you could save the images in `NSUserDefaults` using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) 
                                          forKey:key];
```

But keep in mind that `NSUserDefaults` is meant for storage of preferences, not images. You better save the images in the documents folder and store the path in `NSUserDefaults` (as suggested by Wain).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save images the way you want. In your case, array contains just pointers to the images, not images itself. So, one way around is, as @Wain suggested, writing image to the disk, and add path of the saved image to the array, and then saving that array to the `NSUserDefaults`. You can save image to the disk by converting it to the `NSData`, and writing it in `Documents` or `tmp` folders of application sandbox. In order to convert image to the `NSData`, you could use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality)` method, and in order to write data to the disk, use `writeToFile:atomically` method of `NSData`.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can save them into the `Document` directory:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView1.image);
NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/imageName.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

And save their URLs in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *default = [NSUserDefault standardDefaults];
[defaults setObject:imagePath  withKey:@"saved image "];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And simply retrieve image:

```
UIImage *customImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```