# How to store UIImage in NSMutableArray without loss of quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsmutablearray, photos

I have a problem, I use the Photo framework, and when I do that (images is a NSMutableArray) :

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager]requestImageForAsset:lastAsset targetSize:CGSizeMake(150, 300) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {

        [images addObject:result];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",result,[images objectAtIndex:0],[images lastObject]);

 }];
```

I have these results for the size of my UIImages in my console :

700,700 60,40 700,700

I don't understand why, and when I add an image of my NSMutableArray which is named "images" :

```
view.image = [images objectAtIndex:index];
```

I have all my images in very bad quality (I think they are all stored in 60,40 in my images NSMutableArray).
Or I want to recover theses in their original quality (700,700 not in 60,40) to display theses with a good quality.

Thanks a lot everyone !!

Comment: Convert it to an NSData object.  Please note that you need to know that NSArrays and NSDictionaries can only hold classifications of variables that are called "Cocoa Collections".  You might need to convert it to a 64 bit NSData object, but if you look in this direction of "Convert UIImage to NSData", you should get going in the right direction.  Also, make sure you are converting the UIImage (check the class on the object with [myImage class]) not a UIImageVIew.

Comment: never store image object in an array. Convert it into nsdata and store it.

Comment: This might help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237198/saving-an-mutable-array-of-images-and-loading-them

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do that :

[imagesToDisplay addObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(result)];

And after :
view.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imagesToDisplay objectAtIndex:index]]

But despite of that, my photos are in a bad quality on my view. I want theses in their original quality when I display.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution of my problem.

The solution is to add this option :

```
        PHImageRequestOptions* options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc]init];
        options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
        options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
        options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionUnadjusted;
        options.synchronous = YES;
```

to my request.

We can see the deliveryMode which is very important for keep a good image quality.

Thanks for help everyone !

Comment: As testa said,it solved all my problems in blink.Even I can get thumbnail and full HD image later.It's a Developer Pre-Release.[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageRequestOptions_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014400-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4),which handles all download and receiving of images.This[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841795/ios-8-photokit-get-maximum-size-image-from-icloud-photo-sharing-albums) can help.